# Cylindrical sigma algebra answers countable questions only.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I got a missing link in some in the following (standard) textbook question:

Show that the cylindrical sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}_T$ on $\mathbb{R}^T$ (equals $\bigotimes_{t\in T}\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$) with, say, $T=[0,1]$ "answers" countable questions - i.e.
$$
\mathcal{F}_T=\left\{\{ x\in\mathbb{R}|x(t_1),x(t_2),...\in A| t_1,t_2,...\in T, A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\{t_1,t_2,...\}}  \}\right\}=\bigcup_{S \text{ countable}} \mathcal{F}_S.
$$

I verified that the r.h.s. is a sigma algebra, but I can't convince myself that it contains all the cylindrical sets as claimed (correctly) e.g. here: [Cylindrical sigma algebra and continuous functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201130/cylindrical-sigma-algebra-and-continuous-functions).

Why isn't it possible to find a projection $\pi_t$ that is $\mathcal{F}_T/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable, but not $\mathcal{F}_S/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ - e.g. in the same way one can construct a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ which is not in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a cylindrical set? I am asking because the fact that each cylindrical set is in $\mathcal F_S$ for some countable $S$ seems to be a direct consequence of the definition.

Comment: Given an index set $T$ and a collection of $\sigma$-fields $\mathcal{F}_t$ on spaces $\Xi_t$, $t\in T$. Pick any $A_t \in\mathcal{F}_t$. Then $A_t\times \prod_{s\neq t} \Xi_s$ is a one-dimensional cylinder set.

Comment: And your definition of a cylinder set in general (not necessarily "one-dimensional") would be?