# An element not in this (baby) cylindrical sigma-algebra?

Tags: probability, general-topology

Consider $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$, a generic element of which I denote by $x= \{x(i)\}_{i \in \mathbb N}$. Three possible sigma-algebras on this set are :

- The sigma-algebra $\mathcal E$ generated by the singletons.
- The cylindrical sigma-algebra $\mathcal F$ generated by $\{x(i)^{-1}(\{j\}) : i \in \mathbb N, j \in \{0,1\}\}$
- The powerset $\mathcal G$

They verify $\mathcal E \subset \mathcal F \subset \mathcal G$, and the first inclusion is strict since $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ is not countable.

The sigma-algebra generated by the singletons is the set of the countable or co-countable  subsets. So $x(1)^{-1}(\{0\})$ is an element of $\mathcal F \setminus \mathcal E$.

> Similarly, in case the inclusion $\mathcal F \subset \mathcal G$ is strict, can one construct an (as explicit as possible) element of $\mathcal G \setminus \mathcal F$ ?

I thought about transposing the classical example of the Vitali set of the real line but this does not seem so easy... Also, the kind of example here [Cylindrical sigma algebra and continuous functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201130/cylindrical-sigma-algebra-and-continuous-functions) does not directly apply in the very simple setting we consider.

Comment: The **non-constructive** proof is: $\mathcal F$ has cardinal $\mathfrak c$ but $\mathcal G$ has cardinal $2^\mathfrak c$.

Comment: Which already clarifies the fact that the inclusion is strict, thanks @GEdgar